# How to play the video streamed from Android device to Server?

Tags: android, video, header, streaming, mp4

I have an application that streaming Video/Audio from Android device to Server
Streaming are fine but when I save the streamed data fro MediaRecoreder I can't play the file

Android code :

```
String hostname = "000.000.000.000";
int port = 0000;
Socket socket = null;
try {
socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(hostname), port);
} catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
}
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);
MediaRecorder recorder =  new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
recorder.start();
```

server side :

```
Socket userSocket = socket.accept();
//DataInputStream dis;
dis = new  DataInputStream(userSocket.getInputStream());
while(true){
        dis.read(buf , 0 , buf.length);
        saveBufferToFile(buf);
}
```

Now the I save the buffer using FileOutStream .write(); method but the out put file can't be played at all.

after research I understand that I need to add the mp4 headers to the file before I write the data on it BUT I don't know how to do this !?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the MPEG4 container is more than just "headers" to video data.

Secondly, the server side code does not look correct to me.  I assume it is Java.  Specifically:

```
dis = new  DataInputStream(userSocket.getInputStream());
while(true){
    dis.read(buf , 0 , buf.length);
    saveBufferToFile(buf);
}
```

Specifically, [`DataInputStream.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) does not necessarily read the entire length of the buffer.  The JavaDocs say:

> An attempt is made to read as many as len bytes, but a smaller number
>   may be read, possibly zero.

I suspect the file you are writing to disk is corrupted.  You can confirm this by comparing the number of bytes sent by the client and the size of file.  My gut say the file will be significantly larger.

To fix it you'll need to take not of the bytes read in by `read()`, and only write those to bytes to disk.   The rest of the buffer is effectively garbage, ignore it.

Comment: Ok, I'm sure that I read all the bytes and I save the file on the device and on the server ! this will not solve the problem ! while I was searching about this problem ! I found that I need to add the header of the file and the footer and these contains the content length of the file and I can't know how much I saved ! so I think this is UN-solvable issue and I should find anther way to stream the data from the Android device to the server.

Comment: @daigoor:  The problem is not with reading all the bytes.  It is with writing too many bytes.  On each loop you are writing the entire buffer, weather or not it was filled on the read.  The likelihood of reading from the network and filling the buffer on each read for the duration of the file is almost none.  Until you resolve this problem you'll never make it farther.

Comment: I know .. but I'm currently far away from this error now I start doing something else and I stopped working on this project untill I finish what I have.